# Set a string as index of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Given the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4])
print(df)
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

I would like to modify it as

```
print(df)
   0
A  1
A  2
A  3
A  4
```

Comment: Why would you want an index that is not unique? This seems redundant to me. Additionally indexing will be problematic

Comment: On the face of it, this is a bad idea (See EdChum's comment).  Giving you the benefit of the doubt, maybe this is a part in a larger process that you feel you need to accomplish in order to get the larger task completed.  If that is `True` then there is certainly a way to better accomplish that task without doing this.  Otherwise, we are just trying to accomplish parlor tricks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this specific case you can use:

```
df.index = ['A'] * len(df)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `set_index`

```
In [797]: df.set_index([['A']*len(df)], inplace=True)

In [798]: df
Out[798]:
   0
A  1
A  2
A  3
A  4
```

Comment: Don't use inplace=True, always be explicit and reassign. inplace does a copy anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the df, you can add it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4],index=['A']*4)
df
Out[325]: 
   0
A  1
A  2
A  3
A  4
```